# react js, MUI table pagination items not aligned vertically

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI with it's pagination but the items in the pagination footer are not aligned vertically. how to fix it?

This image shows the problem:
[image]

Footer:

```
return (
    <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={totalCount}
          page={page}
          onPageChange={handleChangePage}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5,10,25,50,100]}
          onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}

        />
);
```

Footer is used here

```
<div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div style={{ width: '75%'}}>
          <DataGrid 
            rows={data}
            columns={columns}
            getRowId={(row)=>row.sysId}
            rowHeight={45}
            pageSizeOptions={[3, 6]}
            slots={{
              footer: () => (
                <Footer
                  page={pageNo-1}
                  totalCount={totalCount}
                  handleChangePage={handlePageChange}
                  rowsPerPage={pageSize}
                  handleChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                  />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
```